# PDF file download automatically once form is submitted successfully

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am very new to BackboneJS. I need to make PDF file download automatically once the form is submitted. PDF may be a static link or static path. Please help me in achieving this guys, as i have sleepless nights :(

i am able to submit the form and get thank you page. But i need file to be downloaded after submit,

```
   <form id="contactForm1" name="consultData" data-toggle="validator" 
    role="form" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
     placeholder="Name*" id="contact_full_name1" name="fullName" value="
     <%=userProfile ? userProfile.displayName : ''%>" required/>
                            <span class="glyphicon form-control-
         feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors  
              text-left"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" 
      placeholder="Email*" id="contact_email_id1" name="email" value="
      <%=userProfile ? userProfile.email : ''%>" required 
      pattern=".+@.+\..+" title="<abc>@<xyz>.<com>"/>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors 
                text-left"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
       id="contact_contact_num1" placeholder="Contact Number*" value="
     <%=userProfile ? userProfile.phone : ''%>" required  
        pattern="\d{10}" title="e.g. 9876543210"/>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors 
         text-left"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control"  
        id="contact_city">
                                <option> City </option>
                                <option> Bangalore </option>
                                <option> Mangalore </option>
                                <option> Pune </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button id="contactus-submit-btn1"  
       class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-kitchen" type="submit" 
       data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> submit">
                                submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

this is the js,

```
  define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!/templates/landing_pages/kitchenlanding_page.html',
  'cloudinary_jquery',
  '/js/mgfirebase.js',
  '/js/consultutil.js',
  '/js/analytics.js'
   ], function($, _, Backbone, kitchenlandingPageTemplate,   
    CloudinaryJquery, MGF, ConsultUtil, Analytics) {
    var KitchenLandingPageVIew = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.page',
            ref: null,
            renderWithUserProfCallback: function(userProfData) {
                $(this.el).html(_.template(kitchenlandingPageTemplate)({
                    'userProfile': userProfData
                }));
                $.cloudinary.responsive();
            },
            render: function() {
                var authData = this.ref.getAuth();
                MGF.getUserProfile(authData, 
             this.renderWithUserProfCallback);
            },
            initialize: function() {
                Analytics.apply(Analytics.TYPE_GENERAL);
                this.ref = MGF.rootRef;
                $.cloudinary.config({ cloud_name: 'xyz', api_key: 
          '49252'});
                _.bindAll(this, 'renderWithUserProfCallback');
            },
            submit: function(e) {
                if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return;
                e.preventDefault();

                var name = $('#contact_full_name1').val();
                var email = $('#contact_email_id1').val();
                var phone = $('#contact_contact_num1').val();

                var query = $('#contact_city').val();


                ConsultUtil.submit(name, email, phone, query, null, 
                null, null, null);

                window.App.router.navigate('/thankyou-consult-page', {
                    trigger: true
                });

            },
            events: {
                "submit": "submit"
            }
        });

           return KitchenLandingPageVIew;

              });
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried...

Comment: @TJ Please check the updated question . Please vote up, as i don't know how to use stackoverflow

Comment: Did you try something regarding the file upload? there are jquery plugins like https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload. Once the download is triggered then you can move to your thank you page? Or jus trigger the download from thank you page?

Comment: No .. I saw that link previously which you provided me . But, i am unable to integrate it. i need some small help to integrate that

Comment: ok then your question should be about the integration issue you are facing... explain how you tried to integrate it what error/issue you got so that someone can find what went wrong...

Comment: I deleted that code yesterday . will do again freshly .. if you can help me here posting a answer, it would be glad @TJ